# R: apply a function to all rows that orders a subset and completes a calculation if a condition is met

Tags: r, function, if-statement, apply

i want to apply a function to every row, after
ordering a subset of that row according dependent on an if/else statement. after which populating a new column in the dataframe with the results. i have over two million rows, so a for loop to do this is very inefficient.

given the following dataframe: (edited for r2evans)

```
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(LETTERS[1:3], ncol=1),matrix(sample.int(100,size=15),nrow=3,ncol=5))

> df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  A 77 79 32  5  4
2  B 57 24 68 65 45
3  C 66 60 82 74 22
```

is there a way to apply the following loop to each row without a for loop as i actually have over 2630800 rows?

```
df$num <- 0
df[2:7] <- sapply(df[2:7],as.numeric)
names(df) <- c("first_name", "sec", "A", "B", "C", "D", "num")
```

the names of the columns are required for the if statement below:
(also edited to only sort once)

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
     row = sort(df[i,3:6])
     if (df[i,1]==names(row)[4]) {
         df$num[i] = row[3]/(row[3]+row[4])
     } else {
         df$num[i] = row[4]/(row[3]+row[4])
     }
 }
```

such that i get this outcome:

```
> df
  first_name sec  A  B  C  D       num
1          A  77 79 32  5  4 0.2882883
2          B  57 24 68 65 45 0.4887218
3          C  66 60 82 74 22  0.525641
```

i'm not sure how to do this with apply, was thinking something like this? although this does not work and i am not sure how to incorporate the if/else conditions:

```
df$num <- apply(df, 1, function(x) unlist(x[3:6][order(x[3:6])][3]/(x[3:6][order(x[3:6])][3]+x[3:6][order(x[3:6])][4])))
```

Comment: `(df[i,3]==names(row[order(row)])[4])` makes no sense in this context: `df[,3]` is `$A` which is a numerical vector, and `names(.)[4]` is always `character`, which is at best a slightly faulty comparison. Further, with this sample data, it will never match, so your `if` statement *never* executes the "then" block, always the "else" block.

Comment: With that, the same results can be had with `df$num <- df[,6] / rowSums(df[,5:6])` (for all rows at once). BTW: recalculating `row[order(row)]` four times is innefficient/silly, just define it as `row = sort(df[i,3:6])` and use `row` in place of `row[order(row)]` *everywhere* in that loop.

Comment: Lastly, a defensive-programming nit: while `1:nrow(df)` works, if you ever use this in an automated fashion then this will fail if (even accidentally) it is given a 0-row frame. For instance, if `df0 <- df[0,]`, one would expect that it would not iterate at all, but `1:nrow(df0)` actually iterates twice, effectively over `1:0` (which makes sense), and the `for` loop will error. A safer approach is `seq_len(nrow(df))`, which will truly have a 0-length vector if the frame has 0 rows, which means the `for` loop will not run.

Comment: @r2evans i've edited the original to reflect that the if statement can and is called. and thank you for your note - no longer calling the order() function four times

Comment: @r2evans also noticed my mistake in typing - have also amended the original post in accordance to your first post - the comparison is with the first column, not the third

Comment: FYI, for your next question with randomness: please use (and include) `set.seed(42)` (or some number). It's not as strictly necessary here since we can copy the `df` output itself, but that's not always safe to assume (many reasons); when building random data programmatically, setting the seed allows us to have *precisely* what you have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little brute-force approach with some hard-coding (column indices).

```r
cols <- 3:6
sorted2 <- t(apply(df[,cols], 1, sort, decreasing = TRUE))[,1:2]
sorted2
#   [,1] [,2]
# 1   79   32
# 2   68   65
# 3   82   74
df$num <- ifelse(df[,1] == names(df)[cols][max.col(df[,cols])],
                 sorted2[,2], sorted2[,1]) /
            rowSums(sorted2)
df
#   first_name sec  A  B  C  D       num
# 1          A  77 79 32  5  4 0.2882883
# 2          B  57 24 68 65 45 0.4887218
# 3          C  66 60 82 74 22 0.5256410
```

Notes:

- I define `cols` so that if you change the columns, you only need to change it once.
- Your code tends to compare if `first_name` matches a column name, and from that determine if you use the "maximum" or the "second-maximum" values from the `cols` columns, and then divide *that* number by the sum of the two-max numbers. For this, I calculate `sorted2` which always has the max in column 1 and the 2nd-max in column 2, making `rowSums` and max/2nd-max access immediate/easy.
- I could have used `df$first_name` instead of `df[,1]`, your choice.

This should work much better than a `for` loop or `sapply`, since it is completely vectorized.

Comment: ah! that's great. you split out the steps. and really smart, you only need the first and second highest anyway to get the fraction. thank you! and it is much faster